# Programs for drawing figures?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I need to start writing up my dissertation, and I need a program for drawing figures. You guys have any recommendations? Also, thanks to my advisor, I have an i-pad with pen. Looking for a bunch of recommendations!! Thanks

Comment: IPE is what I've grown accustomed to using lately. -- http://ipe.otfried.org/

Comment: What about TikZ?

Comment: I've heard good things about Inkscape.

Comment: Yeah, tikz is probably best but it is so hard to get a handle on, at least for me.

Comment: It's really important to know what kind of figures you need to be drawing.  I get a lot of use out of GeoGebra for calculus and geometry figures, but it wouldn't be as ideal for graph theory.

Comment: One of my professors commented that he really liked my figures in one of the homeworks I turned in in grad school and asked what I used.  I had just used mspaint..... I don't recommend it in general, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: Try https://app.diagrams.net/

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest best software for which you can draw easily is https://www.mathcha.io/

Comment: I'm using mainly ''xy'' and rarely the Latex built-in drawing facility ''picture''.

Comment: IPE is fantastic, but don't sleep on Powerpoint either.

Comment: Inkscape will allow you to draw really complex figures including TeX.

Comment: I'm not going to be drawing any really complex figures I don't  think. But what do you mean that it allows me to draw relaly complex figures including TeX? Isn't TeX just a markup language ?

Comment: Inkscape is a free illustration software but has TeX supporting addons in the sense that you can write TeX-commands in your illustrations in order to add formulas or symbols into your illustrations. Just look it up on google, you will eventually find interesting examples.